# how to set block-device-mappings during aws ec2 run-instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

sof,

how to set block-device-mappings during aws ec2 run-instances?

I am new to awscli.

I pip installed it into my python env.

I got this example to work ok:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d2c924b2 --instance-type m4.large
```

How to enhance the above shell command so I launch with more disk space?

I tried this syntax and it failed:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d2c924b2 --instance-type m4.large --block-device-mappings {"DeviceName":"/dev/sda1","Ebs":{"VolumeSize":100}}
```

Comment: "It failed" in what way?  Please remember to fully describe what happened that was unexpected, including the exact errors, if any.

Comment: Move that json ```{"DeviceName":"/dev/sda1","Ebs":{"VolumeSize":100}}``` to a file and run the command as below:```aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d2c924b2 --instance-type m4.large --block-device-mappings file://mapping.json```

Refer: To launch an instance using a block device mapping section in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Comment: [{"DeviceName":"/dev/sda1","Ebs":{"VolumeSize":100}}] moved to mapping.json fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how it works without moving the code to separate JSON:

```sh
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ami-d2c924b2 \
    --instance-type m4.large \
    --block-device-mappings 'DeviceName=/dev/sda1,Ebs={VolumeSize=32}'
```