# Does --instanceType option decide the EBS volume size mounted to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-ebs

In the below command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ${VAR1} --key-name ${VAR2} --security-group-ids ${VAR1} \
  --instance-type t2.micro --subnet ${VAR3} --iam-instance-profile Name=whatever
```

---

Volume type can be EBS or EFS or whatever.

Does `--instance-type t2.micro` decide the volume(type & size) mounted to EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance type is independent of EBS volume size. Instance type primarily determines the CPU and RAM available to the instance. You would need to specify `--block-device-mappings` to start an instance with a specific EBS volume size. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290499/how-to-set-block-device-mappings-during-aws-ec2-run-instances) for an example.